# How can i make a Regex to use with xPath and ImportXML?

Tags: regex, xpath

I allow myself to expose my problem, because I would like to create a regular expression, using XPath, to then import the data via importXML.

I know the method with javascript, but not how to integrate a REGEX with XPath and importXML.

I would like to retrieve for example on the page the number of employees : https://www.societe.com/societe/zeeko-507593416.html (info in French : Tranche d’effectif)

I would like to retrieve the info: 3 to 5 employees by making a regular expression on the word employee (salariés), which allows to then recover the workforce.

I was able to make an XPath code `//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/a/@href`  to get info in a table, but that's not accurate enough. Could you tell me how I could integrate a REGEX?

Thank a lot !

Comment: Search around and you'll find that the consensus is: don't use regex with html/xml! Is `3 à 5 salariés` your desired output?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but XPath 2.0 has a matches() function that allows you to search for nodes based on a regular expression match. There is no equivalent in XPath 1.0.

Comment: @JackFleeting : yes, the result is to have in output : 3 à 5 salariés. 
the code must be able to work on every other page then, to always know in result: xx to xx salariés. 

That's why I had thought of a regex, but I do not know if it's possible, or if another way is possible.

Thanks

Comment: @MichaelKay I explained a little more detail on the post above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JackFleeting Hello, it works perfectly thank you very much, I tried to see how you did and tested on similar research, it really helped me a lot to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this xpath expression, and let me know if it works:

```
//table[@id="rensjur"]//td[contains(text(),"Tranche")]/following-sibling::td/text()
```

Comment: Thanks !  I will test this today, and I'll let you know